# react-bootstrap-table2 search is not working on formatted cells

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-table, react-bootstrap-table

I need help on including the formatted data into the search functionality. For some reason the formatted links are not included in the search

```
function docFormatter(cell, row, rowIndex) {
  return (
    <a href={${row.doc.doclink}}>
       {row.doc.docname}

    );
  }

const columns = [
  { dataField: "sno", text: "S.No" },
  {
    dataField: "doc",
    text: "Document Name",
    formatter: docFormatter,
    filterValue: docFormatter,
  },
];
```

I have a customer formatter and that returns a anchor tag with a text. the search is not working on this.

I looked document https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-search.html#search-on-formatted-data

```
..., {
  dataField: 'type',
  text: 'Job Type',
  formatter: (cell, row) => types[cell],
  filterValue: (cell, row) => types[cell] // we will search the value after filterValue called
}
```

I did'nt understand how to implement this by referencing this. Please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working model fixing this issue

```
function docFormatter(cell, row, rowIndex) {
  return (
    <a href={${row.doc.doclink}}>
       {row.doc.docname}

    );
  }

function docFormatterFilter(cell, row) {
  return cell.docname;
}

const columns = [
  { dataField: "sno", text: "S.No" },
  {
    dataField: "doc",
    text: "Document Name",
    formatter: docFormatter,
    filterValue: (cell, row) => docFormatterFilter(cell, row),
  },
];
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm encountering the same issue but can't find solution.

```
function docFormatterFilter(cell, row) {
  return row.nom;
}
export const fieldsUser = [
  {
    dataField: 'id',
    sort:true,
    text: '',
    formatter: (cell, row) => {
      return (
      <div className={`flex-grow-1`}>
        <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <h4 className="m-0">{row.nom}</h4>
          <small className={ `role-groupe text-center ${row.role==='s' ? 'bg-danger' : row.role==='a'?'bg-success':'bg-primary'}` }>{row.role_label}</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    )},
    filterValue: (cell, row) => docFormatterFilter(cell, row),
    filter: textFilter({
      caseSensitive: false,
      comparator: Comparator.LIKE,
    }),
    classes: 'col-12',
  }
];
```

Nothing works since a week.